# java: package MongoClientOptions does not exist

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, log4j, spring-batch

I am trying to upgrade the log4j version to 2.16.0 with the springboot version 2.6.2 .After upgrading My code is failing with the below error while connecting to MongoDB database .Which version of spring-data-mongodb is compatible with the springboot version 2.6.2 .Could anyone suggest which version of Mongodb is the proper version for the below Java code . Any help would be appreciated

Error:(51,27) java: package MongoClientOptions does not exist . My pom.xml as like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SampleService</name>
    <description>Project for  Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
       

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <uberJar>true</uberJar>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Application Java Code :

```
package com.sample;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
    //private String uri;
    private String database;
    private String host;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private int port;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Application Running.......");
        
    }

    public @Bean
    com.mongodb.MongoClient mongoClient() {

        MongoClientOptions.Builder mongoClientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true)
                .sslEnabled(true).applicationName("Sample-Service");
        try {

          KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/mnt/secrets/keystore.jks")) {
                keystore.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (CertificateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, "password".toCharArray());

            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(keystore);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());
            mongoClientOptions.sslContext(sslContext);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MongoClientOptions mops = mongoClientOptions.build();
        MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createCredential(username, database, password.toCharArray());
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(host, port), mongoCredential, mops);
        return mongoClient;
    }

//    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
//    public void setUri(String uri) {
//        this.uri = uri;
//    }

    public String getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database}")
    public void setDatabase(String database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.username}")
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.password}")
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `pom.xml` is asking for mongodb-driver-sync 4.2.3.  Some of the classes moved or were retired in the 4.x version; for example, `com.mongodb.MongoClient` is now `com.mongodb.client.MongoClient`.  Your code appears to be 3.x API compatible.  You will have to spend a few minutes to rework your options setup to be compatible with the new classes.  See the API docs https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/apidocs for more.

**UPDATED**

I took a look and the migration to the new classes is not trivial and I hadn't used non-connection string based material in a long time so I reworked the critical parts of the code above.  Note that `credential`, `sslsettings`, and `connectionstring` objects are designed to be built in slightly different ways which can lead to some confusion at first.

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;  // interface                                                
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;  // factory                                                 
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;  // yes, *not* in the .client hierarchy!                    
import com.mongodb.MongoCredential;
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;


MongoCredential credentials = MongoCredential.createCredential(
                                   "USER", "ADMIN_DB", "PASSWORD".toCharArray());

String conns = String.format("mongodb://%s:%d/?replicaSet=rs0", "localhost", 27017);

MongoClientSettings.Builder mcsb = MongoClientSettings.builder();
MongoClientSettings mcs = mcsb
                .applicationName("Sample-Service")
                .credential(credentials)                                                          
                .applyToSslSettings(sslb ->
                                    sslb.enabled(true)                                           
                                   .invalidHostNameAllowed(true))
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(conns))
                .build();

MongoClient client = MongoClients.create(mcs);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for response .Have modified the code as suggested but it is failing with the below error .   Error creating bean with name 'mongoClient' defined in com.sample.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'mongoClient' defined in com.agcs.cids.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongoClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Comment: ,Could you please suggest how to proceed on this

Comment: I am not an expert on spring or beans but this seems like a runtime error, not a compile-time error.   Are you sure your runtime classpath is picking up the 4.2.3 core and sync jars?

Comment: Is there is a configuration that doesn't involve specifying the ConnectionString? MongoClientOptions would infer it from the spring.data.mongodb.uri parameter, but with MongoClientSettings, specifying a builder disregards the uri property.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should upgrade your dependencies. Please see the [version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/pom.xml#L30) and [pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/spring-data-mongodb/pom.xml#L99)

Please try:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- reactive: Do you really need it? --> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

### Suggestion

If you use `spring-boot`, and you can try `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` to auto config.

Comment: ,Thank you for the valuable solution .I have modified the pom xml as suggested and the compatible versions is resolved but it is failing with the below error after the updating the pom xml .Could you please suggest on this com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
 at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:707) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_231]

Comment: This exception may be due to a problem with Mongo configuration. You should check the mongo is ok or try to change the spring boot mongo config, like use url. The config is work for me: `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:123456@127.0.0.1:27017/admin?authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1`

Comment: Thank you But I am using as spring boot properties as secrets  in openshift container .And also I am using the MongoClientSetting to set the properties .Not able to use have used MongoClientURI as it throwing and error 
Cannot resolve symbol 'MongoClientURI'                                   spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=${MONGO_AUTH_DB}
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_HOST}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${MONGO_PORT}
spring.data.mongodb.username=${MONGO_USER}
spring.data.mongodb.password=${MONGO_PWD}

Comment: @Buzz Moschetti ,I have tried as suggested by you but it is failing with the com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
 at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadExcep
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket Closed